# yielding values in for loop scala

Tags: scala

I have 3 codes 1st is main code and remaining 2 codes uses for loop ,functionality of both codes is same .But both generate different o/p.
Main code=>

```
class user(var name:String,var id:Int, var gender:Option[String])
{
override def toString="("+ name+","+id+","+gender+")"
}
object a
{
def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={
 var mm=Map(1-> new user("jh",189,Some("Male")),2->new      user("gh",12,None),3
->new user("io",100,Some("Female"))
 def getkey(i:Int)=
 { mm.get(i)
 }
```

Code 1 =>

```
var b=for{
h<-getkey(1)
i<-h.gender} yield i
print(i)
}
}
```

Code 2=>

```
var b=for{
h<-getkey(1)
i=h.gender} yield i
print(i)
} 
}
```

**1st code has o/p some(Male) andd 2 nds o/p has Some(Some(Male))**
**Why both codes generate different o/p? If I replace <- with = in getkey(1) I get error .Why do we get it ?What is the use of <- in for ?**

Comment: The Examples 1 and 4 [on this page of the official tutorial](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html) explain exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a slightly simplified version of your sample code:

```
class User(var name: String, var id:Int, var gender: Option[String])

val mm = Map(
  1 -> new User("jh", 189, Some("Male")),
  2 -> new User("gh", 12, None),
  3 -> new User("io", 100, Some("Female"))
)
def getkey(i:Int) = mm.get(i)
```

**Code snippet 1**:

```
for {
  h <- getkey(1)
  i <- h.gender
} yield i
```

can be translated to:

```
getkey(1).flatMap(_.gender)
// res1: Option[String] = Some(Male)
```

**Code snippet 2**:

```
for {
 h <- getkey(1)
 i = h.gender
} yield i
```

`i = h.gender` is an assignment and the `for-yield` is no different from:

```
for {
 h <- getkey(1)
} yield h.gender
```

and can be translated to:

```
getkey(1).map(_.gender)
// res2: Option[Option[String]] = Some(Some(Male))
```

Comment: Have you made the screenshot of 5555 rep? Can I upvote already? :)

Comment:   my next goal is 6666.